# Condition for positive function such that $f(t)\leq Ct^{2}$?

Tags: integration, analysis

Let $f$ be a positive monotone increasing function. Is it true that $$\int_{1}^{\infty}{\frac{tdt}{f(t)}}=\infty\Rightarrow \frac{f(t)}{t^{2}}\leq C, t\geq 1,$$ for some constant $C$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not true; consider $f(t):=t^2\log t$. This $f$ is monotone increasing for $t\ge 1$, yet
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{tdt}{f(t)}=\int_1^\infty\frac{dt}{t\log t}=\int_0^\infty\frac{du}{u}
$$
using the substitution $u:=\log t$.

---

EDIT: To avoid the division by zero at $t=1$, an alternative is $f(t):=1+t^2\log t$, for which we have
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{tdt}{f(t)}=\int_1^\infty\frac{tdt}{1+t^2\log t}=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{2u}du}{1+e^{2u}u}
\ge\int_1^\infty\frac{e^{2u}du}{1+e^{2u}u}\ge\int_1^\infty\frac{du}{1+u}.
$$

Comment: You might want to modify this slightly to avoid $f(1)=0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Good catch. I've added a version with $f(1)>0$.